# How to use gopls without internet access

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode to write Go. And I have vscode-go installed. To enable language server, I set `useLanguageServer` to true. Under internet, everything works well, it can hover, jump and so on. But I need to work without internet connection. In this situation gopls won't work. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`microsoft/vscode-go` issue 2767](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2767#issuecomment-533776135) did report that  `gopls` seems to connect to an internet address to determine something, which could be the reason is is not starting.

Considering [`gopls` has just released a new 0.2.0 version](https://twitter.com/FiloSottile/status/1194056152285351937), check first you have the latest (`go get http://golang.org/x/tools/gopls @ latest`, assuming you can get an internet connection just for the upgrade), and try again.